# SQL: How to ask for multiple counts from the same table within a join

Tags: mysql, heidisql

Trying to find 3 separate counts within one column of a table, each with separate WHERE clauses. I've got 2 tables in the query, so one join. Thought this looked correct but it will not run:

```
SELECT stores.caption,

COUNT (
            WHEN tasks.created_at BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30' 
            AND tasks.deleted_at IS NULL) 
            AS TaskTotal , 

 COUNT (
            WHEN tasks.created_at BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30' 
            AND tasks.deleted_at IS NULL 
            AND tasks.completed_at IS NULL) AS TaskOutstanding, 

COUNT (
            WHEN tasks.created_at BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30'     
            AND tasks.deleted_at IS NULL 
            AND tasks.completed_at IS NULL 
            AND tasks.deadline < '2019-05-16') AS TaskOverdue

    FROM tasks
    FULL JOIN stores ON tasks.store_id=stores.id
    GROUP BY stores.caption;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. MySQL does not have `FULL` join implemented. You are likely to need only a `LEFT` join (from `stores` to `tasks`):

   ```
   FROM stores 
        LEFT JOIN tasks
        ON tasks.store_id = stores.id
   ```
2. You can't have `WHERE` or `WHEN` in a `SELECT` expression like you try. There is a `FILTER` feature in standard SQL but that has not been implemented either in MySQL. There are however `CASE .. WHEN` expressions you can use just fine. Example:

   ```
   COUNT (
       CASE WHEN tasks.created_at BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30' 
                 AND tasks.deleted_at IS NULL
           THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) 
       AS TaskTotal ,
   ```

So the query can be written:

```
SELECT
    stores.caption,
    COUNT (
        CASE WHEN tasks.created_at BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30' 
                  AND tasks.deleted_at IS NULL
            THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) 
        AS TaskTotal ,
    COUNT (
        CASE WHEN tasks.created_at BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30' 
                  AND tasks.deleted_at IS NULL
                  AND tasks.completed_at IS NULL
            THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) 
        AS TaskOutstanding ,
    COUNT (
        CASE WHEN tasks.created_at BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30' 
                  AND tasks.deleted_at IS NULL
                  AND tasks.completed_at IS NULL
                  AND tasks.deadline < '2019-05-16'
            THEN 1 ELSE NULL END ) 
        AS TaskOverdue
FROM
    stores 
    LEFT JOIN tasks
    ON tasks.store_id = stores.id
GROUP BY
    stores.caption ;
```

Now, since all 3 expression have a common condition you can simplify by moving that condition to the `ON` clause - assuming that you don't want any more columns without it.

We can also add table aliases and removed the redundant `ELSE NULL` from the case expressions:

```
SELECT
    s.caption,
    COUNT ( t.store_id ) 
        AS TaskTotal ,
    COUNT (
        CASE WHEN t.completed_at IS NULL
            THEN t.store_id END ) 
        AS TaskOutstanding ,
    COUNT (
        CASE WHEN t.completed_at IS NULL
                  AND t.deadline < '2019-05-16'
            THEN t.store_id END ) 
        AS TaskOverdue
FROM
    stores AS s
    LEFT JOIN tasks AS t
    ON t.store_id = s.id
    AND t.created_at BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30' 
    AND t.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY
    s.caption ;
```